# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated crashing on iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I am facing a crash on iOS 6.0. I have a view controller from which I present a navigation view controller modally and then from the navigation stack I present another view controller modally and finally to dismiss the whole modal stack I pass the following message to my first view controller from where I showed the navigation controller.

Now this works fine on iOS below 6.0. How should I handle this?

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Does it work if you do animated as "NO"?

Answer (score 4):

I had this similar crash as well and one of the things helped me solve it was adding:

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Lets say you add a method to appDelegate called 'makeMeNumberOne:(UIViewController *)vc':
(I know you use the 'modal' versions, they are deprecated in iOS6, switch to 'presented' variants)
. Also I assume you can find the navigationController, if this is a problem add a comment I'll further expand this, and assume you are using ARC.)

- the parameter you have is a strong reference, it holds the current presented viewController, lets call it pvc
- ask the navigationController for its viewControllers, and get the last one
- as a debugging tool, verify that this vc has a non-nil presentedViewController property
- message the last view controller above:

  [lastOne dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
      [navigationController.viewControllers = @[pvc];
  }];

Comment: If I do so, it does not crash but it does not remove the entire modal stack as well. So, my view hierarchy is View 1 --> View 2(Modal) --> View 3 (Modal). And when I keep a strong reference to View 2 and from View 1, I am passing dismiss message to View 2 , it removes just the view 3 and not the view 2. I want to come back to view 1 directly.

Answer (score 3):

maybe because dismissModalViewController is deprecated in iOS6? Try

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```