# dismissViewControllerAnimated crash when dismiss many screen same time

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am facing a problem in iOS 5 va iOS 6. That is I have 3 view controllers, A, B and C. A presentModalViewController B, and B presentModalViewController C. Now at C I have a button to call A dismissViewControllerAnimated. That means B and C will dismiss. This workflow work successfully in iOS 4.3, but now I have problem in iOS 5 and 6.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the viewController you are going to present, set

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle =UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12746304/482533